How can I get the value of a nested YAML key with a hyphen in its name in Helm?
I want to create a service in Kubernetes using a Helm chart. Below is my values.yml file that contains the key and value:
my-app:
  ports:
    http: 8000


Here’s my Helm chart for creating the service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: {{ .Values.my-app.ports.http | int }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.my-app.ports.http | int }}
  type: ClusterIP


I encountered errors with the above Helm chart.
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: parse error at (my-app.yaml:12): bad character U+002D '-'
My Helm information is
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.16.3", GitCommit:"cfd07493f46efc9debd9cc1b02a0961186df7fdf", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.22.7"}

How can I extract port and targetPort from the values?

Consider renaming this to myApp in the values file, so you don't hit this syntactic issue.  This specific value doesn't need to be configurable at deploy time, though: I'd most likely hard-code port: to whatever port number the container listens on by default, and targetPort: 80 to use the standard HTTP port.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: my-deployment
spec:
replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
containers:
- name: my-container
image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
env:
- name: MY_ENV_VAR
value: {{ .Values.nested-key["sub-key1"] }}
